# Counting Results in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm having trouble using COUNT in SQL...The following query returns two rows, but then returns the raps column as 137. So I believe it's counting the total number of operation_id columns in the dataset instead of from the results.

Is there any way to make it count only the columns from the results, so that raps returns as 1 in each of the columns? I would then use PHP to add them together.

//Query

```
  SELECT DISTINCT hrap_id,
                    operation_id,
                    COUNT (operation_id) AS raps,
                    operation_type
      FROM view_rappels
      WHERE year = '2013' AND crew_id = '4'
  GROUP BY hrap_id, operation_type, operation_id
```

//Results

```
10.00   702020000.00    137.00  operational
1.00    702020000.00    137.00  operational
```

Comment: did you try SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT operation_id) AS raps FROM view_rappels?

Comment: If you know it'll always be 1 - which it will be as the `operation_id` is part of the group by (unless you have any null values in which case you'll get zero) - why bother with the count at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put DISTINCT inside of the count function like so

```
COUNT(DISTINCT operation_id) AS raps
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that was possible.